# Add subtoal as new row in data flow task SSIS

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

SSIS Data flow task

`Source: Stored Procedure @ SQL Server 
Dest:   Excel`

Stored Procedure Results:

`User   Score
 Jim    15
 Betsy  10`

I need to add a new *row* to the result set which is total of score before I dump it into the excel file. So the result should look like this:

`User   Score
 Jim    15
 Betsy  10
Total   25`

what is the best way to achieve this via SSIS, there are several ways to calculate a new column based on existing columns, but I'm not sure how to add a new row. Do we have any aggregation functions similar to SSRS?, I tried Aggregation transformation in SSIS as follows:

`Score --> Sum
 User  --> Group By`

Doesn't give me what I want. Ideas please.

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked fine for me. 
Use AddRow() method via SSIS script task, here is the 3 line code in C#

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{

    int total = 0;
    public override void PreExecute()
    {
        base.PreExecute();
    }

    public override void PostExecute()
    {
        base.PostExecute();

    }

    public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {

        total = total + Row.Score;

        GrandTotalBuffer.AddRow();              // Add a new row
        GrandTotalBuffer.Score = total;         // Assign calculated value of the variable 'total' to the Column 'Score' for the newly added row
        GrandTotalBuffer.User = "Total";        // Assign value 'Total' to the Column 'User' for the newly added row
    }

    public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
    {

    }

}
```

And here is how the data flow task looked like:

[image]

The `Grand Total` contains calculated output `Output 0` contains regular rows from `OLE DB Source` thus needing to use the `Union All`.